# JupyterLab LaTeX extension

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I've successfully installed the jupyterlab-latex extension from GitHub however when I try to compile the .tex file I get this error:

`` LaTeX command `xelatex -shell-restricted -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error -file-line-error -synctex=1 untitled` errored with code: 1 ``

An error message also appears in the JupyterLab window:

> File Load Error for untitled.pdf

Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: What happen if you try to compile the same .tex file without jupyter? What is the error?

Comment: There is no error when compiling without Jupyter, using xelatex in the command line is flawless.